# TcpClient wait for CRLF

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm writing a class library to communicate with a PLC by using TCP. The communication is based on sending a data string which is terminated by a CRLF and next waiting for an acknowledge string (also terminated by a CRLF) to confirm the data is received (yes I know this is also included in the TCPIP protocol, but this is another discussion).

Currently I'm facing two major problems:

1. I'm setting the TcpClient.SendTimeout property, however it looks like when the data is send (by TcpClient.Client.Send), the sender does not wait for the receiver the data to be read. Why?
2. Because of the sender is not waiting, an acknowledge string and immediately the next data string can be send. So, the receiver is getting two packages. Is there a way to read the buffer only till the first CRLF (acknowledge) and leave the next data string in the buffer for the next TcpClient.Client.Read command.?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: Why would you expect the sender to wait for the data to be read? That's generally not how TCP works... you can keep writing without blocking until you hit the limits of whatever buffers are involved. Next, it sounds like you're assuming that a single call to `Socket.Read` will read the data written by a single call to `Write` at the other end. That's not how streaming protocols work. It sounds like you should use a `TextReader` and `TextWriter` pair, then you can call `ReadLine` to read the next line of text, for the acknowledgement.

Comment: The reason is to synchronize the sequence of the PLC to the sequence of the application on the PC. To put it in other words, you can start with the next step when you are sure the PLC is also ready and visa-versa.

Comment: Sure, I can see why you'd want that to happen in your case - but I don't know why you expect that to be the socket's default behaviour. It's simply not how TCP works. As I say, you probably want to layer a reader/writer on top of the socket.

Comment: Looks like I solved the issue, by having a solution to problem 2. Instead of reading a complete array I just read one byte till I receive one telegram and leave the next telegram for the next function call.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a streaming protocol. There are no packets that you can program against. The receiver must be able to decode the data no matter in what chunks it arrives. Assume one byte chunks, for example.

Here, it seems the receiver can just read until it finds a CRLF. `StreamReader` can do that.

> the sender does not wait for the receiver the data to be read

TCP is asynchronous. When your Send completes the receiver hasn't necessarily processed the data. This is *impossible* to ensure at the TCP stack level. The receiving app might have called Receive and gotten the data but it might not have processed it. The TCP stack can't know.

You must design your protocol so that this information is not needed.

> I just read one byte till

That can work but it is very CPU intensive and inefficient.